# From a remote SSH session, how can I get the screen resolution of the physically connected monitor?

Tags: 18.04, ssh, display, display-resolution, xrandr

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS Desktop.

I'm connecting to the desktop via remote SSH session.

I'm trying to get the current resolution for the currently active local session.

I found these seemingly relevant questions:

- [How do I find out my screen resolution from a shell script?](https://superuser.com/q/196532)
- [How can I get the monitor resolution using the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/584688/how-can-i-get-the-monitor-resolution-using-the-command-line)
- [How do I change local display resolution via SSH?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/155985/how-do-i-change-local-display-resolution-via-ssh)

However, `xdpyinfo` returns the following error:

```
xdpyinfo:  unable to open display "".
```

and `xrandr` returns a similar error:

```
Can't open display
```

I'm assuming this is because there is no display connected to my remote SSH session.  I've tried switching (`su`) to the same user as the local session, but the error is the same - I assume for the same reason: no display related to that SSH session.

So, I tried the suggestions from my third link above.

```
$ export DISPLAY=:0
$ xdpyinfo
No protocol specified
xdpyinfo:  unable to open display ":0"
```

and

```
$ xrandr --display :0
No protocol specified
Can't open display :0
```

How can I poll the display on the active local session for resolution (dimension) info from a remote SSH session?

Comment: I am not sure whether I understand your question correctly. Might these two questions, plus answers, be of help to you? - https://askubuntu.com/questions/1066721/headless-server-no-monitor-no-graphics - https://askubuntu.com/questions/1061354/vnc-with-virtual-display-partly-solved-dock-missing

Comment: I don't see how either of those questions would be relevant.  They both discuss headless servers.  I am connecting to an Ubuntu Desktop install with a currently active local session running on a physically connected monitor.  I want to poll the local session for the current resolution of the physically connected monitor.

Comment: I thought it could be relevant as you describe that "there is no display connected to my remote SSH session."

Comment: I see, but both of your links are about completely headless servers with no physical display, and the solutions seem to revolve around connecting to a "virtual" display.  I need to connect to the physically connected display to poll its current resolution.

Comment: what are you attempting to achieve ?  to launch a UI app on remote box and display locally ?

Comment: nope.  I'm just doing a remote install of several kiosk systems, which might have monitors of varying resolutions.  To properly setup the kiosk, I need to know what resolution it will be running at.  I can setup a VNC connection to the locally active session to check the current resolution, but multiplied by several installs it would be much more efficient if I could determine the resolution from the SSH session where I am doing the rest of the setup.

Answer (score 5):

## **1.** You can try this command

```
cat /sys/class/drm/*/modes
```

or to get more info

```
grep . /sys/class/drm/*/modes
```

To get the status of each device, type

```
grep . /sys/class/drm/*/status
```

## **2.** Or read the monitor screen data

> **Extended Display Identification Data (EDID**): This standard
>   defines data formats to carry configuration information, allowing
>   optimum use of displays.

A monitor typically supports multiple resolutions and refreshrates. Of course someone will prefer the maximum (physical) one.

To read this monitor data, try one of these solutions:

- **edid-decode**

  If not installed, type

  ```
  sudo apt install edid-decode
  ```

  Then read the `edid` file

  ```
  edid-decode /sys/class/drm/card0-eDP-1/edid
  ```
- **read-edid**

  Install with

  ```
  sudo apt install read-edid
  ```

  Then read via i2c the screen monitor data  and parse it

  ```
  sudo get-edid | parse-edid
  ```
- **Hexdump the edid data**

  In case edid-tools are not installed, you can dump the `edid` hex-file, e.g.:

  ```
  hd /sys/class/drm/card0-eDP-1/edid
  ```

  To encrypt this hex file  take a look at  [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Display_Identification_Data) or download the [edid specifications](http://read.pudn.com/downloads110/ebook/456020/E-EDID%20Standard.pdf).

Comment: This *sort of* works.  It looks like it is giving me *available* resolutions for the connected device, but it doesn't give me the *actual, current* resolution.  This probably works for my purposes as I can assume the highest available resolution is the one currently in use, but it doesn't really strictly or definitively answer my question.

Comment: You edited your post several times since I replied.  I haven't tried the 2. solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

X-Windows has a command that gives you information about *a display*. You can start it with:

```
xdpyinfo | less
```

When running via SSH, though, you will not have access to X-Windows unless you use the `-X` option and the server allows remote connections through ssh (which is the case by default on Ubuntu).

```
ssh -X <other-desktop>
```

If it looks like the ssh daemon does not let you connect that way (you'll be able to get the ssh session, but with an error saying X11 is not available) then edit the ssh server settings on your destination desktop:

```
sudo vim /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

and search for X11 and make sure the following is not commented out (no starting `#` character) and that it says `yes`:

```
X11Forwarding yes
```

If you had to change that, restart the ssh daemon:

```
sudo systemctl restart sshd
```

If you restarted `sshd`, make sure to reconnect (<kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd> to exit and then `ssh -X ....` again).

Once connected and the X-Windows error is out of the way, in your ssh session you can do:

```
DISPLAY=:0 xdpyinfo | less
```

This gives you the info about display `:0` which, in most likelihood, is the display of the user currently running (if you have many users, you may have multiple screens so `:0` may not be correct).

Search the output for:

```
dimensions:    3840x2160 pixels (1016x572 millimeters)
```

and now we know the resolution. This example shows a 4K display.

So I think all you were missing was the `-X` on the `ssh -X ...` command.